# (C) Inserting into a Linked List struct is not reflecting within other functions

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am attempting to insert nodes into the head of a Linked List object, but the updated head does not appear to reflect in other functions.

My professor has dictated that our insert functions need a List struct and not a pointer to the List struct, but the List struct contains a pointer to a node - the head.

```
typedef struct Node {
void *Object;
struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct{ 
         Node *head; 
} List;
```

My insertAtHead function resembles this:

```
int insertAtHead(void* data, List list) {
   int error = 0;
   Node * head = list.head;
   Node * newNode = createNode(data, &error);
   newNode->next = head;
   list.head = newNode;
   return error; }

Node * createNode(void * Object, int * error) {
    Node *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pointer == NULL) {
        *error = 1;
        return NULL;
    }
    pointer->Object = Object;
    pointer->next = NULL;
    *error = 0;
    return pointer;
}
```

However, my getSize function prints 0 - it only finds the dummy node I use with initList.

```
int getListLength(List list) {
    Node * head = list.head;
    int i = 0;
    while (head->next != NULL) {
        printf("Test\n");
        i++;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return i;
}

List initList(int * error) {
    int * q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *q = 1;
    // I use an integer here solely to prove 
    List list = {createNode(q, error)};
    return list;
}
```

I'm pretty confused on what I'm doing wrong. I suspect there's some pass-by-value/reference shenanigans going on, but I deal with the head pointer in all of my functions using the list. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to clarify further. Thank you!

Comment: Not necessarily. My professor has stated that the prototypes shouldn't use pointers to refer to the List struct. Ideally, I'd prefer to do it the way the question you linked works.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
int insertAtHead(void* data, List list) {
   int error = 0;
   Node * head = list.head;
   Node * newNode = createNode(data, &error);
   newNode->next = head;
   list.head = newNode;
   return error; }
```

deals with a copy of used as an argument object of the type List. So changing the copy is not reflected on the original object.

You need to pass the original object by reference through a pointer to it. For example

```
int insertAtHead(void* data, List *list) {
    int error = 0;

    Node * newNode = createNode(data, &error);
 
    if ( error == 0 )
    { 
        newNode->next = list->head
        list->head = newNode;
    }
   
    return error; 
}
```

If you are not allowed to pass the original object of the type List by reference then you have to return from the function the modified object of the type List as for example

```
List insertAtHead(void* data, List list, int *error ) {
    Node * newNode = createNode(data, error);
 
    if ( *error == 0 )
    { 
        newNode->next = list.head
        list.head = newNode;
    }
   
    return list; 
}
```

And you will need to assign the returned object to the object of the type List in the caller.

Also this function

```
List initList(int * error) {
    int * q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *q = 1;
    // I use an integer here solely to prove 
    List list = {createNode(q, error)};
    return list;
}
```

does not make a sense.

Initially the list should be empty. So initialization of the list consists from initialization of the data member `head` to `NULL`.

Also the function `getListLength` should look at least like (if you are not allowed to pass the list by reference)

```
int getListLength(List list) {
    Node * head = list.head;
    int i = 0;
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("Test\n");
        i++;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I understand the answer, but I'm forced to do it without pointers as per my lab document - apologies as I wasn't super clear about this on my question.

Comment: @QuantumBlink It does not make a sense to declare the function accepting a copy of the pointer to the lost. At least in this case you need to return the object of the type List instead of the type int,.